# cmake: how to include/compile files out of the project directory?

Tags: build, cmake, project, external-project

I have this directory structure:

```
projects/
    project1/
        src/
            main.cpp
            CMakeLists.txt
    project2/
        src/
            file1.h
            file1.cpp
            test1.cpp
```

The top level projects directory cannot be considered a top level project, but just a collection of unrelated projects, so I would not put a `CMakeLists.txt` file at that level.

I want project1 to include files from project2 without specifying the full path, e.g.:

```
// main.cpp
#include "file1.h"
```

And I also want implementation files of project2 to be built in project1.

I need project2 not to be a library, but just use its files like if they were part of project1.

I am using `cmake`, and this is the `CMakeLists.txt` file I wrote (it does not work):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(project1)
add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(../../project2/src)
```

Even specifying the full path to project2 does not work: `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR)/../../project2/src`

I get "fatal error: file1.h: no such file or directory" from `make`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use external include files, this works:

```
include_directories
```